# Why can't I set gap of 8 in the Cytoscape fcose constraints demo?

Tags: cytoscape.js

Using the cytoscape-fcose demo (constraint) at https://ivis-at-bilkent.github.io/cytoscape.js-fcose/demo/demo-constraint.html, I set up a couple of constraints to be:

[image: constraints]

The goal is to have vertical centers of the n6 and n7 nodes aligned and to reduce the separation between the nodes to 8 pixels.

The result I get looks like:

[image: result image]

The vertical centers are aligned, but the gap is larger than expected.

Is this a bug? Or is there some way to achieve a smaller gap?